# The command "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js" exited with code 2

Tags: webpack, build, .net-core

could anybody guide me what I should be looking at?

I have to fix something in webpack but I've never been using this before.

If I do 'dotnet build' I get multiple errors like these (I don't think they are a problem?)

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./researcherApp/typings/modules/angular-ui-bootstrap/index.d.ts:31:13
      TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'ITimepickerConfig'.

  ERROR in [at-loader] ./researcherApp/typings/modules/angular-ui-bootstrap/index.d.ts:32:13
      TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'ITooltipOptions'.
```

and as well an error

```
error MSB3073: The command "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js" exited with code 2.
```

I guess this last one is giving me a problem since that one is in red and all the others are just white (in the vsc terminal)

kind regards

Comment: How many times are `ITimepickerConfig` and `ITooltipOptions` defined in your ` ./researcherApp/typings/modules/angular-ui-bootstrap/index.d.ts` file? Based on the error message, I'm guessing that you have them listed multiple times.

Comment: @JamieTaylor 

For ITimepickerConfig for example I can find this:
`export type ITimepickerConfig = angular.ui.bootstrap.ITimepickerConfig;`
and this
`interface ITimepickerConfig {
            hourStep?: number;
            minuteStep?: number;
            secondStep?: number;
            showMeridian?: boolean;
            meridians?: Array<string>;
            readonlyInput?: boolean;
            mousewheel?: boolean;
            arrowkeys?: boolean;
            showSpinners?: boolean;
            showSeconds?: boolean;
            templateUrl?: string;
        }`

Comment: So there are multiple references to `ITimepickerConfig`, which is the equivalent of declaring two variables with the same name, in the same scope. Did you create the `./researcherApp/typings/modules/angular-ui-bootstrap/index.d‌​.ts` file manually?

Comment: @jamie Tayler: I didn't create this project, they just asked me to change something in webpack but I don't know it yet

Comment: @jamieTayler ah wait I think I missed an important bit...
above the exports there is an `import * as angular from 'angular';`

and underneath is 
`module angular { export namespace ui.bootstrap { interface ITimepickerConfig { ....} }`